# How to convert float into string without a dot in Java

Tags: java

Is there any way to transform float number into string without a dot(.).

For example:

## Float a=0.6

into

## String b="06"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the dot using `String.replace()`

```
    float a = 0.6f;
    String s = a + "";
    s = s.replace(".", "");
    System.out.println("s = " + s); // prints: s = 06
```

Comment: maybe im just tired but I dont understand why is error appearing
http://prntscr.com/6mm28t

Comment: @MarkoPetrePetričević because you can't put this block of code in a class - you have to put it in a method and call it, or simply put it in main().

Comment: You made my day, thx. I was using class for testing, but it works in my method =)